# Include a header in a parent folder and getting problems with links

Tags: php, header, hyperlink, include-path

I'm trying to organize my php-project by puting some files into folders. When I change my include from

```
include("header.php");
```

to

```
include("../header.php");
```

The link stops working and so does the css-stylesheet. How can I fix this bug, or am I doing something wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of links like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/stylesheet.css">
```

Make them all relative to the document root (start with `/`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylesheet.css">
```

Same for links etc.

Answer (score 0):

You've started to call the file from a subfolder it appears, so if your links are dynamic ones, ie

```
<a href="a/link/here.php">
```

They'll break - you'll need to set yourself hard paths such as:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/a/link/here.php">
```

The same goes for any CSS links etc.

Comment: Well, the domain is not strictly necessary if it's still the same. Also, `http<>https` troubles ahead.

Comment: Yes true - I've been using the domain method in my framework with a 'const' for so long I completely forgot you could use a root slash also!